# Can you assign AWS parameter store data source's value to a variable in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to read a value from AWS Parameter Store and assign its value to a variable.

```
# data source
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "environment" {
  name = "environment"
}

# variable
variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "AWS Environment Name"
  default     = data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value
}
```

Is this possible?

I know you can use `data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value` wherever I need to use a variable but is it possible to simplify it by assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. However, you can use local variables [1] for that. For example:

```
locals {
  environment = data.aws_ssm_parameter.environment.value
}
```

You would then reference that value elsewhere in the code with `local.environment`.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals